# reVC Compiling fails under OS X 10.13.6, refers to system's OpenGL.framework

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, macos-high-sierra

OS X 10.13.6, Intel

The original project was pre-compiled by the Devs for 10.15+, but I have no intention of installing system updates unless absolutely necessary.

Managed to get around other issues (with libsndfile and other missing libraries -- fetched them via brew), but now issue seems to be caused by built-in one.

Possible to resolve this issue under 10.13.6?

Output below:

```
make config=release_macosx-amd64-librw_gl3_glfw-oal
==== Building librw (release_macosx-amd64-librw_gl3_glfw-oal) ====
==== Building reVC (release_macosx-amd64-librw_gl3_glfw-oal) ====
Running prebuild commands
"./../printHash.sh" "./../src/extras/GitSHA1.cpp"
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
GitSHA1.cpp
Linking reVC
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GLAD_GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_GLAD_GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_gladLoadGLES2Loader", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_gladLoadGLLoader", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glActiveTexture", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::setTexture(int, rw::Texture*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::setFilterMode(unsigned int, int, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterRenderFast(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::setRenderState(int, void*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::wdgl::Texture::bind(int) in librw.a(wdgl.o)
  "_glad_glAttachShader", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glBindAttribLocation", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glBindBuffer", referenced from:
      CustomPipes::vehicleRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::worldRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::glossRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::rimRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::rimSkinRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      WorldRender::AtomicFirstPass(rw::Atomic*, int) in custompipes_gl.o
      WorldRender::RenderBlendPass(int) in custompipes_gl.o
      ...
  "_glad_glBindFramebuffer", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::bindFramebuffer(unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::setFrameBuffer(rw::Camera*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glBindRenderbuffer", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterCreate(rw::Raster*) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glBindTexture", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::bindTexture(unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::setTexture(int, rw::Texture*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterRenderFast(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::setRenderState(int, void*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::wdgl::Texture::upload() in librw.a(wdgl.o)
      rw::wdgl::Texture::bind(int) in librw.a(wdgl.o)
      ...
  "_glad_glBindVertexArray", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glBlendFunc", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glBufferData", referenced from:
      ScreenDroplets::InitDraw() in screendroplets.o
      FlushBuffer() in screendroplets.o
      rw::gl3::instance(rw::ObjPipeline*, rw::Atomic*) in librw.a(gl3pipe.o)
      rw::gl3::defaultInstanceCB(rw::Geometry*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*, int) in librw.a(gl3pipe.o)
      rw::gl3::skinInstanceCB(rw::Geometry*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*, int) in librw.a(gl3skin.o)
      rw::gl3::openIm2D() in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::gl3::im2DRenderPrimitive(rw::PrimitiveType, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      ...
  "_glad_glBufferSubData", referenced from:
      FlushBuffer() in screendroplets.o
      rw::gl3::im2DRenderPrimitive(rw::PrimitiveType, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::gl3::im2DRenderIndexedPrimitive(rw::PrimitiveType, void*, int, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::gl3::im3DTransform(void*, int, rw::Matrix*, unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::gl3::im3DRenderIndexedPrimitive(rw::PrimitiveType, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::wdgl::uploadGeo(rw::Geometry*) in librw.a(wdgl.o)
  "_glad_glCheckFramebufferStatus", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glClear", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::clearCamera(rw::Camera*, rw::RGBA*, unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glClearColor", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::clearCamera(rw::Camera*, rw::RGBA*, unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glCompileShader", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::compileshader(unsigned int, char const**, unsigned int*) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glCompressedTexImage2D", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterUnlock(rw::Raster*, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glCopyTexSubImage2D", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterRenderFast(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glCreateProgram", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glCreateShader", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::compileshader(unsigned int, char const**, unsigned int*) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glCullFace", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glDeleteBuffers", referenced from:
      ScreenDroplets::Shutdown() in screendroplets.o
      rw::gl3::freeInstanceData(rw::Geometry*) in librw.a(gl3pipe.o)
      rw::gl3::destroyNativeData(void*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3pipe.o)
      rw::gl3::instance(rw::ObjPipeline*, rw::Atomic*) in librw.a(gl3pipe.o)
      rw::gl3::closeIm2D() in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::gl3::closeIm3D() in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
  "_glad_glDeleteFramebuffers", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::destroyNativeRaster(void*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glDeleteProgram", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::destroy() in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glDeleteRenderbuffers", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::destroyNativeRaster(void*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glDeleteShader", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glDeleteTextures", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::destroyNativeRaster(void*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glDepthFunc", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glDepthMask", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::clearCamera(rw::Camera*, rw::RGBA*, unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glDisable", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::clearCamera(rw::Camera*, rw::RGBA*, unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glDisableVertexAttribArray", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::disableAttribPointers(rw::gl3::AttribDesc*, int) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::teardownVertexInput(rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::defaultRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
  "_glad_glDrawArrays", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::im2DRenderPrimitive(rw::PrimitiveType, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::gl3::im3DRenderPrimitive(rw::PrimitiveType) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
  "_glad_glDrawElements", referenced from:
      FlushBuffer() in screendroplets.o
      rw::gl3::drawInst_simple(rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*, rw::gl3::InstanceData*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::drawInst_GSemu(rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*, rw::gl3::InstanceData*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::drawInst(rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*, rw::gl3::InstanceData*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::defaultRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::im2DRenderIndexedPrimitive(rw::PrimitiveType, void*, int, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::gl3::im3DRenderIndexedPrimitive(rw::PrimitiveType, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      ...
  "_glad_glEnable", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::clearCamera(rw::Camera*, rw::RGBA*, unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glEnableVertexAttribArray", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::setAttribPointers(rw::gl3::AttribDesc*, int) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::setupVertexInput(rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::defaultRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::wdgl::setAttribPointers(rw::wdgl::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(wdgl.o)
  "_glad_glFramebufferRenderbuffer", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::setFrameBuffer(rw::Camera*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glFramebufferTexture2D", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::setFrameBuffer(rw::Camera*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterCreate(rw::Raster*) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::destroyNativeRaster(void*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glGenBuffers", referenced from:
      ScreenDroplets::InitDraw() in screendroplets.o
      rw::gl3::instance(rw::ObjPipeline*, rw::Atomic*) in librw.a(gl3pipe.o)
      rw::gl3::defaultInstanceCB(rw::Geometry*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*, int) in librw.a(gl3pipe.o)
      rw::gl3::skinInstanceCB(rw::Geometry*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*, int) in librw.a(gl3skin.o)
      rw::gl3::openIm2D() in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::gl3::openIm3D() in librw.a(gl3immed.o)
      rw::wdgl::uploadGeo(rw::Geometry*) in librw.a(wdgl.o)
      ...
  "_glad_glGenFramebuffers", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterCreate(rw::Raster*) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glGenRenderbuffers", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterCreate(rw::Raster*) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glGenTextures", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::allocateDXT(rw::Raster*, int, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterCreate(rw::Raster*) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::wdgl::Texture::upload() in librw.a(wdgl.o)
  "_glad_glGenVertexArrays", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glGenerateMipmap", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterUnlock(rw::Raster*, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glGetCompressedTexImage", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glGetFloatv", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glGetIntegerv", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glGetProgramInfoLog", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glGetProgramiv", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glGetShaderInfoLog", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::compileshader(unsigned int, char const**, unsigned int*) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glGetShaderiv", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::compileshader(unsigned int, char const**, unsigned int*) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glGetString", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glGetTexImage", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glGetUniformBlockIndex", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glGetUniformLocation", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glLinkProgram", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glPixelStorei", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterUnlock(rw::Raster*, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glReadBuffer", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glReadPixels", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterLock(rw::Raster*, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glRenderbufferStorage", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::rasterCreate(rw::Raster*) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
  "_glad_glScissor", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::clearCamera(rw::Camera*, rw::RGBA*, unsigned int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glShaderSource", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::compileshader(unsigned int, char const**, unsigned int*) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glStencilFunc", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glStencilMask", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glStencilOp", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushGlRenderState() in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glTexImage2D", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::allocateDXT(rw::Raster*, int, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterCreate(rw::Raster*) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterUnlock(rw::Raster*, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::wdgl::Texture::upload() in librw.a(wdgl.o)
  "_glad_glTexParameterf", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::setFilterMode(unsigned int, int, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
  "_glad_glTexParameteri", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::setTexture(int, rw::Texture*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::setFilterMode(unsigned int, int, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::setRenderState(int, void*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::deviceSystemGLFW(rw::DeviceReq, void*, int) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
      rw::gl3::allocateDXT(rw::Raster*, int, int, int) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::gl3::rasterCreate(rw::Raster*) in librw.a(gl3raster.o)
      rw::wdgl::Texture::upload() in librw.a(wdgl.o)
      ...
  "_glad_glUniform1i", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glUniform3fv", referenced from:
      CustomPipes::vehicleRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::glossRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::uploadRimData(bool) in custompipes_gl.o
      CPostFX::RenderOverlayShader(rw::Camera*, int, int, int, int) in postfx.o
  "_glad_glUniform4fv", referenced from:
      CustomPipes::vehicleRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::worldRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::glossRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in custompipes_gl.o
      CustomPipes::uploadRimData(bool) in custompipes_gl.o
      CPostFX::RenderOverlayShader(rw::Camera*, int, int, int, int) in postfx.o
      FlushBuffer() in screendroplets.o
      rw::gl3::flushUniforms() in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
      ...
  "_glad_glUniform4iv", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushUniforms() in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glUniformBlockBinding", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glUniformMatrix4fv", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::flushUniforms() in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glUseProgram", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::Shader::create(char const**, char const**) in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
      rw::gl3::Shader::use() in librw.a(gl3shader.o)
  "_glad_glVertexAttribPointer", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::setAttribPointers(rw::gl3::AttribDesc*, int) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::setupVertexInput(rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::gl3::defaultRenderCB(rw::Atomic*, rw::gl3::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(gl3render.o)
      rw::wdgl::setAttribPointers(rw::wdgl::InstanceDataHeader*) in librw.a(wdgl.o)
  "_glad_glViewport", referenced from:
      rw::gl3::beginUpdate(rw::Camera*) in librw.a(gl3device.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [../bin/macosx-amd64-librw_gl3_glfw-oal/Release/reVC.app] Error 1
make: *** [reVC] Error 2
```

No idea what to try since OpenGL is built-in